# Suma de digitos de un número al cubo

Tags: java, netbeans, algoritmos

Estoy intentando sacar las cifras de un número y elevarlas al cubo y luego sumarlas con las demás cifras pero el valor que obtengo no es el esperado, quisiera saber en qué parte me equivoco. Gracias.

```
  public boolean perfectCube(int n){
    int sum = 0;
    while(n > 0){
      sum = (((n % 10)^3) + sum );
      n /=  10;
      System.out.println(sum);
    } // While
    if(sum == n){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }// If
  } // Fin de método
```

Comment: ¿Qué ejemplos de entrada salida te da? El código lo veo bien, pero creo que la función no hace lo que quieres que haga. Un cubo perfecto es un número en el que una de las cifras al cubo da ese número, no la suma de sus cifras. Por ejemplo, 125 es cubo perfecto porque 5^3 = 125. Así que tu `if` debería ir dentro del `while`, sin `else`, y fuera del `while` poner `return false;`, además, tendrías que reiniciar "sum" dentro del `while`, para hacer el cálculo con cada dígito independientemente de los otros. Todo esto, si es que tengo razón en lo del cubo perfecto, claro.

Comment: Es que el número cubo perfecto que me han explicado es ese, en el que sus cifras al cubo sumadas da el mismo número tal y como lo expliqué en la pregunta, los datos de salida son estos. 0
6
8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en tu operador `^`. Ese operador existe, pero no es para indicar exponentes. [Es un XOR a nivel de bit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Para elevar al cubo puedes multiplicar el numero por sí mismo, o puedes usar [`Math.pow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-). Ojo que `Math.pow()` devuelve un `double`, no `int`.

```java
int numero = 5;
int cubo = 5 * 5 * 5; // Resultado: 125
double cubo2 = Math.pow(5, 3); // Resultado: 125
```

Answer (score 0):

según la explicación que das de tu problema, estas buscando si los números son triangulares, hay mucha documentación de ese tipo de números, un método rápido para identificarlos es que cumpla con la condición de que `8n+1` sea un cuadrado. Tomando en cuenta eso, el método quedaría:

```
public boolean perfectCube(int n) 
{ 
    int x = 8*n+1;
    if(Math.sqrt(x)==(int)Math.sqrt(x)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Valida este código y me comentas si es lo que buscas.

Comment: lo acabo de intentar pero el valor no era el indicado, de igual forma gracias por tu aporte investigaré sobre eso que mencionaste, el conocimiento nunca viene mal

Comment: Hola, aprovecho para corregir un error en el código que tenia y bueno si ese no es detalle de tu problema, al menos es una linea diferente de búsqueda.